# Symfony 2 login on two domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, appdomain

We are running a Symfony 2.1 App, that has let's say the domain `www.foo.com` there the login isn't a problem at all. But we have a second site `www.bar.com` which is basically just `www.foo.com/bar` with an proxy rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.foo.com/bar$1 [L,P,NE]
```

This works like a charm too, except for the login. I always get redirected to `www.foo.com/login` and then of course the login cookie is only set for domain `www.foo.com`. Is there a way to tell Symfony about the second domain?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, Symfony 2.1 is quite old so the feature described below will not be available until you upgrade. 2.7 is due out by the end of the month and it's a LTS version, so it might be a good time to do so.

I believe what you are looking for is a separate firewall for the secondary site.  In Symfony you can define a firewall by the hostname:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/firewall_restriction.html#restricting-by-host

So you might have:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        foo_site:
            host: ^foo\.com$
            # ...
        bar_site:
            host: ^bar\.com$
            # ...
```

If you want to be logged in on both at once, you can set the context of the firewall the be the same. By default the context for the two firewalls above would be foo_site and bar_site. Although I'm not sure that this will work since your firewalls are defined by different hosts and would therefore have different cookies.

Here is a link to the firewall context reference:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context

And here is a link to all the default security options. I find this to be pretty useful when trying to see what is available:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration

Good luck!

Comment: Uggh, formatting did not come through correctly. Sorry I will fix that when I get to a computer. On my phone now.